# Cron Exp required

Tags: schedulebatch

Actually I need a cron expression to schedule a class after 2 hour of a account record is created. This schedule class schedule only once. Please provide me cron expression.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the job to run once you can do this as follows:

System.scheduleBatch(batchJob, 'Job Name', 120);

for more details see this http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: I like this approach.  To be clear, you would call this in a trigger after insert on the Account object.   Another approach you could take is using time based workflow to update a field on the account which would trigger the class on Account.  The after update trigger would use Database.executeBatch instead.  This would give button clicky admins the ability to change the time frame through the UI.